# Counting rows between specifc endpoints

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Context**

I have a table with 3 columns: `DATE`, `SERIAL` and `SEQUENCE`. Each row represents a product. Each product has a unique `SERIAL` value. There are multiple products in a day, signaled by the `DATE` value and each day has any given number of products ordered by `SEQUENCE`.

Example of what the table I'm using looks like:

| DATE | SERIAL | SEQUENCE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10-11-2023 | 12345 | 1 |
| 10-11-2023 | 98765 | 2 |
| 10-11-2023 | 82963 | 3 |
| 10-12-2023 | 84621 | 1 |
| 10-12-2023 | 31972 | 2 |
| 10-12-2023 | 42869 | 3 |
| 10-13-2023 | 24534 | 1 |
| 10-13-2023 | 67458 | 2 |
| 10-13-2023 | 79426 | 3 |

**Goal**

Find how many rows back the starting point is from the endpoint.
The starting row is determined by DATE and SERIAL which are both user input.

The ending row is determined by DATE and SEQUENCE which are constants. The DATE will always be Date.Time.Now.ToString() and the SEQUENCE will always be '1' to have the first row with the current date be the endpoint.

For simplicity sake, Date.Time.Now.ToString() will just use '10-13-23'

**Issue**

I am having trouble creating an SQL statement that can specify these start and end points without effecting the number of rows being counted. To be clear I want to count how far back the starting point
is from the end point; meaning the starting row should be counted.

**User Input**

```
txtDate.Text = 10-11-23
txtSerial.Text = 98765
Date.Time.Now.ToString() = 10-13-23
```

```
"SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM Table
 WHERE
 DATE BETWEEN '" + txtDate.Text + "' AND '" + Date.Time.Now.ToString() + "'
 OR (SERIAL = '" + txtSerial.Text + "' AND DATE = '" + txtDate.Text + "')"
```

- Counts all rows: Yes
- Sets Correct Start Date: No
- Sets Correct End Date: No

I'm currently getting a row count of 9.

I should be getting a row count of 5 because:

| DATE | SERIAL | SEQUENCE | .... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10-11-2023 | 12345 | 1 |  |
| 10-11-2023 | 98765 | 2 | My inputs specify this row as my *Start point* |
| 10-11-2023 | 82963 | 3 |  |
| 10-12-2023 | 84621 | 1 |  |
| 10-12-2023 | 31972 | 2 |  |
| 10-12-2023 | 42869 | 3 |  |
| 10-13-2023 | 24534 | 1 | Sequence 1 of the current date is always my *End point* |
| 10-13-2023 | 67458 | 2 |  |
| 10-13-2023 | 79426 | 3 |  |

As seen above, my starting point is 5 rows behind the endpoint. But it seems my statement is counting all rows within the 10-11-23 - 10-13-23 date range.

Comment: I have three words for you: "gaps and islands".

Comment: I prepared several examples for you - can you add some goals or query examples, which you want to reach? https://dbfiddle.uk/iHAtxyQN

Comment: How is this related to C#?

Comment: At a best guess, @NetMage , due to that massive injection vulnerability the OP demonstrates.

Comment: C# is a language of types - what are the types of the database columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest breaking up the query into three sections. The first section is the rows with same date, starting with the desired serial # to the last on that date:

```
(created_date = '2023-10-11' and
   sequence >= (select sequence from mytable where created_date = '2023-10-11' and serial = 98765))
```

The second section are the rows with dates between the starting date and the ending date:

```
(created_date > '2023-10-11' and created_date < '2023-10-13')
```

The third section is the one row of the ending date:

```
(created_date = '2023-10-13' and sequence = 1)
```

Putting it together, this query returns all the desired rows:

```
select *
from mytable
where (created_date = '2023-10-11' and
       sequence >= (select sequence from mytable where created_date = '2023-10-11' and serial = 98765))
      or
      (created_date > '2023-10-11' and created_date < '2023-10-13')
      or
      (created_date = '2023-10-13' and sequence = 1)
```

Since you want to "count back" from the end row, you can count all the rows except the ending row, and get the count:

```
select COUNT(*)
from mytable
where (created_date = '2023-10-11' and
       sequence >= (select sequence from mytable where created_date = '2023-10-11' and serial = 98765))
      or
      (created_date > '2023-10-11' and created_date < '2023-10-13')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It does seem to work in most cases. My only issue is that through repeated testing I sometimes recieve the following Error: ```Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression``` 

I'm not quite sure what may cause this, could it be the "OR" statment is running into issues with the data?

Comment: @ServalChan That is likely because the sub-query `(select sequence from mytable where created_date = '2023-10-11' and serial = 98765)` is returning more than one row, which I didn't think should happen based on your description. Run the sub-query by itself and see if any query returns more than one row.

Comment: after a bit of testing, it turns out my data itself had some repeating values. But I've since resolved that issue and your answer works perfectly. Thank you very much!